# Why does WSP Deployment Type 'ApplicationServer' require features to be manually installed?

Tags: deployment, feature, solution-package, installation, farm-solution

When I create a WSP with Deployment Type set to WebFrontEnd and deploy, all of the features contained within are automatically installed. Features that are set up as ActivateOnDefault="TRUE" (Farm or WebApp scoped) or AutoActivateInCentralAdmin="TRUE" thus are also automatically activated simply by deploying the WSP.

The same does not occur when the WSP Deployment Type is set to ApplicationServer. I have to manually install each feature in the WSP one by one from a script. This has been the behavior I've seen in 2007 and 2010, however I have not been able to find this documented as correct anywhere.

Is there a reason this behaves the way it does?

I am using ApplicationServer as my deployment type so that I can package timer jobs and custom central administration pages and custom actions together into one WSP. Should I just continue to maintain deployment scripts that install each feature one by one after solution deployment, or should I use a different approach in packaging?